# Selenium- How to validate if the element has certain styles

Tags: selenium, automation

I need to write a test script to validate that a button is present on the page and the button becomes sticky and stays attached at the bottom of the screen for mobile breakpoint.

I have already written a script where it resizes the browser window. However, How do i prove that a button remains sticky to the footer no matter how much scrolling user does.

Button retains its id and place in the DOM when its styling changes for the mobile view.

I need solution for all major browsers but if someone can guide me for Chrome that should be good enough.

I have looked into getComputedStyle but i think its bit messy. i am looking for more elegant solution using some library.

Answer (score 1):

This check is baked in selenium - there's a webelement method `isDisplayed()` returning a boolean. Here's a link to the Java bindings - https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed--

And if you're wandering if this is a "real" check is the element in the viewport, here's the webdriver's explanation how it's done - https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#element-displayedness *(in summary: yes, as much as this can be done)*.

Comment: great! I was already using this feature and thank you for confirming it.

Comment: I wanted to assert on some other styles too such as position=fixed for sticky button. so i did something like this:            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
            string minHeight = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return getComputedStyle(callRetailerButtons[0]).minHeight; ");
            minHeight.Should().Be("80px");

Comment: Well, your question sounded like an XY problem - "How to get the computed styles? Why? To be sure it's sticky. Well, this how you'll check it is sticky.", thus I answered you this way. And yes, js `getComputedStyle()` is "The Way" to get the styles :). The issue with stickiness is that it can be accomplished in a number of ways, and it would be very tiresome to verify it through code on the style derivative :) Glad you were on the right track.